# Assign Dialog box view to another view

Tags: android

I am creating a dialog and setting setContentView of a layout. And I am programmatically adding buttons, images to layout in dialog setContentView . Now how I can  assign dialog box view to another view.
That is a layout is assigned to a a view like below

```
 View getview=R.layout.tamil_alphabet_speak_word;
```

Similarly how can I assign the dialog box view to another view. Since I am adding all elements to the view "TamilAlphabets" programmatically  the child are null it returns for the below code.

```
 Alphbetdialog=new Dialog(TamilAlphabets.this);
   Alphbetdialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   Alphbetdialog.setContentView(R.layout.tamil_alphabetsdialog);
    (adding elements to the layout "TamilAlphabets" code
      ..............
             )
   LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)TamilAlphabets.this.getSystemService
   (TamilAlphabets.this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row=inflator.inflate(tamil_alphabetsdialog, Parent,false);
            LinearLayout l1=(LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.alphabetlayout1);                           
            ViewGroup vg=(ViewGroup)l1;
            vg.getChildCount();
```

So I need to assign the dialog box view to another view how do I do that.
I need something like this

```
   View getview=<I need dialog box view>
```

Comment: are you trying to use a custom dialog?

Comment: s I am using custom dialog

Comment: How can I get the custom dialog view and assign to another view.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `Dialog` class directly and instead use `Dialog` subclass's or `DialogFragment`

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html:

> The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following subclasses:
>   
>   AlertDialog
>   A dialog that can show a title, up to three buttons, a list of selectable items, or a custom layout.
>   
> DatePickerDialog or TimePickerDialog
>   A dialog with a pre-defined UI that allows the user to select a date or time.

In any case im guessing that what you want is a custom dialog and what is recomendaded is using the `DialogFragment` class in that case here is an example

Dialog fragment layout

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Dialog class

public class DialogExampleFragment extends DialogFragment {

```
private static final String ARG_PARAM = "extra:PARAM";
private String mText;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();

    mText = arguments.getString(ARG_PARAM);


}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    dialog.setTitle("title");

    return dialog;
}

public static DialogExampleFragment newInstance(String message) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    args.putSerializable(ARG_PARAM, message);

    DialogExampleFragment fragment = new DialogExampleFragment();

    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_example, container, false);




    TextView t = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    t.setText(mText);

    return root;
}
```

}

To show as a dialog

```
DialogExampleFragment.newInstance("Message")
                    .show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Note since a DialogFragment is a fragment it has de advantage of being able to be shown as a Dialog or as a regular fragment you can get all the information on the link i posted above